# Camping stove as a wort heater

Tags: wort, boil, brewing

I'm looking for a way to get a good rolling boil on 5 gallons of wort, on a really tight budget

What are my best options?

Answer (score 2):

Over the years, I have moved from the stove in my kitchen to outdoors using a propane burner.  I have gone through 3-4 different burners looking for n that was both maximally effective and also quiet.  This is what I currently use and by far the best I've found....[Bayou Classic Burner](http://www.brewinternational.com/bayou-classic-banjo-cooker-22-kab6/?gclid=CjwKEAjwqamhBRDeyKKuuYztxwQSJAA1luvGH8HlXizqLju89okjgZ6yGjvPVPZtdtXoIMwYheiRjxoC6tjw_wcB) .  That style of burner is available from a number of sources.

Comment: Yeah, this is what Australians call a NASA burner, because of the sound. My favourite is Italian burner (http://shop.beerbelly.com.au/italian-burner.html). It's not cheap, but is very efficient and quiet.

Comment: Over here we call it a "jet burner".  I started with one of those but it didn't take me very long to switch.  I then went to one of the sand cast burners which was more controllable and quieter.  The one I linked to above is very powerful and nearly silent.

Answer (score 1):

[NASA burner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002913MI)

Pros: it's cheap and powerful.

Cons: it's NOISY.

Comment: Add to the Cons: it burns through propane like there is no tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, a camping burner usually does not offer enough power to heat your wort to proper temps.

In South Africa we have the Cadac brand of camping burners and it takes hours to get your wort to 80, and then you are not even at a rolling boil!

I brought my CA6 [Six ring burner](http://www.seebots.co.za/ring-burners) for about $20.

These burners are very sturdy and will last a long time (do not let them get wet though, they rust quickly). You will need a regulator and a (kg LP Gas bottle. Your gas company should be able to tell you exactly what you need.

Comment: That's a funky looking burner!